# Closing a Question After it Has Been Answered

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Is there any point to closing a question when it has received an accepted answer?

I sometimes run across situations in which a question is being closed that's already been answered (sometimes I get involved too, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862652/a-simple-c-question)) but now I'm beginning to wonder if there's any point to that... when should we be closing such questions, if ever?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We close questions to indicate that they should not have been posted because they were posted contrary to site guidelines. If we don't close them, people come to Meta and say "Look, that question wasn't closed. Why can't I post a similar question?" (yes, this has happened many times) and then people get angry :( or very confused about what is or isn't allowed. We don't like anger or confusion, so we close these questions.

Comment: Ah, all right, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, it is also useful to group together duplicate questions so all follow-up activity (even when already answered) is grouped together under one correct question.